# Can I automatically select / remove clipping / peaks above -3dB in Reaper?

Tags: noise-reduction, distortion, reaper

I have a long recording that I took on a windy day. The wind was intermittent and I was trying to isolate the sound of the snow. I expected there to be some clipping or unwanted loud sections that mask the snow from gusts, planes, etc.

Normally I would remove the clipping and distortion manually but this is a 1hr+ recording and I know you can do a lot with automation and scripts in Reaper.

Is there any script or way to use dynamic split to select or remove everything from ~-3dB to 0dB? I've used it to select quiet spots but can't seem to figure out using it for sections over a certain dB.

Answer (score 1):

izotope RX has a de-clipping tool. This is the tool to use for this application. However in the future this should be used as a learning experience as to how best to record audio in a windy environment.

You should use appropriate wind-protection for your microphones. Rycote blimps and/or lavalier overcovers are the place to start.

In post, try using the Strip Silence feature in protools. This will allow you to vary the parameters in order to strip or extract "silence" from the recording which is effectively what you are looking to do.

Comment: Thats not really what I was asking. I used a dead cat. I'm not new to this. I want to cut out all but the specific sound I wanted. I wasn't trying to record the wind. I was trying to record the sound of snow falling (which is quiet) but there would occasionally be a big gust, loud car, or a plane overhead. I set the gain for the snow for a good snr (~-12dB). That's why I expected clipping.
 
I should have been more clear. I was trying to isolate all the clean parts of just snow by selecting everything over a certain threshold and leaving only parts where the snow can be heard clearly.

Answer (score 0):

A strategy suggestion: Turn too loud sections to full silence. If you are an experienced DAW user you obviously know a way to "duck" one track with another. It's needed often when one makes music mixes.

In this case you use the same audio twice. Then truncate the silent sections. It can be automatic.

I'm afraid you must render the ducking result and work the rest in an audio file editor. See this Audacity silence removal session example: